# google desktop is not indexing outlook 2003 emails

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2003, google-desktop-search

Good Day ,
HAVe the latest version of Google Desktop abd Outlook 2003 .
But the google desktop is not indexing outlook 2003 emails .
HAVe tried following :
Checked "Email" in desktop preferences
Have uninstalled and reinstalled Google desktop.
In register editor -h_key local machine have checked that Google desktop is installed.But its not showwing in outlook-tools-options-other-advanced options-add in manager.

PLease assist.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually select and add the path in your hard drive to your .pst archive in your pc.
If you don´t know the path, in account configuration you have a tab with your mail archive (outlook.pst or something similar).